# Calculating a vectors with its transposed vector

Tags: python, numpy, vector, transpose, scatter-matrix

I'm working on a calculation for a within matrix scatter where i have a 50x20 vector and something that occured to me is that multiplying transposed vectors  by the original vector, gives me a dimensional error, saying the following:

> operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (50,20) (20,50)

What i tried is: `array = my_array * my_array_transposed` and got the aforementioned error.

The alternative was to do, then:

```
new_array = np.dot(my_array,  np.transpose(my_array))
```

In Octave for instance, this would've been a lot easier, but due to the size of the vector, it's kinda hard for me to confirm for ground truth if this is the way to do the following calculation:

[image]

Because as far as i know, there is something related as to whether the multiplication is element wise.

My question is, am i applying that formula the right way? If not, whats the right way to multiply a transposed vector by the non-tranposed vector?

Comment: `*` is scalar multiplication, you want a matrix-matrix product. Use `numpy.dot` or the `@` operator.

Comment: In MATLAB/Octave `.*` is the element-wise multiplication.  `numpy` uses `*`.  `np.dot` is the original function for handling matrix multiplication.  `@/matmul` is a more recent addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `np.dot` formula is the correct one. If you write `array = my_array * my_array_transposed` you are asking Python to perform component-wise multiplication. Instead you need a row-by-column multiplication which is achieved in numpy with `np.dot`.